# File not found Exception in linkedin integration

Tags: java, android, url, oauth, linkedin-api

I tried to integrate linkedin for sharing the data using many tutorials and posts, but nothing helped, after login was not able to move to next page instead redirecting to the previous, finally checked with the keys, using other users key m able to share the posts the problem was in giving the callback url

```
public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL = "x-oauthflow-linkedin"
    + "://" + "litestcalback";
```

Does anybody know how to give the URL?

Stack trace

```
02-06 16:18:49.786: E/AndroidRuntime(393):      at an  droid.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-06 16:18:49.786: E/AndroidRuntime(393):      at and roid.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-06 16:18:49.786: E/AndroidRuntime(393):      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-06 16:18:49.786: E/AndroidRuntime(393):      at jav a.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-06 16:18:49.786: E/AndroidRuntime(393):      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-06 16:18:49.786: E/AndroidRuntime(393):      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-06 16:18:49.786: E/AndroidRuntime(393):      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-06 16:18:49.786: E/AndroidRuntime(393):      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-06 16:18:49.786: E/AndroidRuntime(393): Caused by: oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken
02-06 16:18:49.786: E/AndroidRuntime(393):      at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:214)
02-06 16:18:49.786: E/AndroidRuntime(393):      at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveRequestToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:69)
02-06 16:18:49.786: E/AndroidRuntime(393):      at com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.oauth.LinkedInOAuthServiceImpl.getOAuthRequestToken(LinkedInOAuthServiceImpl.java:172)
02-06 16:18:49.786: E/AndroidRuntime(393):      ... 12 more
02-06 16:18:49.786: E/AndroidRuntime(393): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken
02-06 16:18:49.786: E/AndroidRuntime(393):      at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:521)
02-06 16:18:49.786: E/AndroidRuntime(393):      at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:258)
02-06 16:18:49.786: E/AndroidRuntime(393):      at oauth.signpost.basic.HttpURLConnectionResponseAdapter.getContent(HttpURLConnectionResponseAdapter.java:18)
02-06 16:18:49.786: E/AndroidRuntime(393):      at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.handleUnexpectedResponse(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:228)
02-06 16:18:49.786: E/AndroidRuntime(393):      at   oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:189)
```